# How can user upload video to my website?

Tags: php, youtube

I'm working on a website, I want the user to upload images or videos.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="post">

    <div id="filediv">
        <input name="file[]" type="file" id="file"/>
    </div>

    <br/>

    <input type="button" id="add_more" class="upload"  value="Add More Files"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit" id="upload" class="upload"/>
</form>
```

My `upload.php` does store image value in database, in same way I have to do it to store videos

**uplaod.php**

```
<?php
include "dbConfig.php";
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $j = 0; 

    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];

    $target_path = "uploads/"; 

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) 
    {

        $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png", "mp3", "mp4", "wma");  
        $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]));
        $file_extension = end($ext); 

        //print_r(basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]));
        $target_path = $target_path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1];
        $j = $j + 1;

        if (($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < 1024*1024*1024)   && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) 
        {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) 
            {
                echo $j. ').<span id="noerror">Image uploaded successfully!.</span><br/><br/>';
                $actual_image_name=$_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
                mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO members(avatar) VALUES ('$actual_image_name')");

            }
            else 
            {
                echo $j. ').<span id="error">please try again!.</span><br/><br/>';
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo $j. ').<span id="error">***Invalid file Size or Type***</span><br/><br/>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

This works fine for uploading images but not for uploading videos.

Comment: What does not "works fine" mean?

Comment: Mayhap the video file is too big? - Check your error logs

Comment: It's very unclear task. Please specify what kind of files you are triing to upload

Comment: to answer your question in the way you ask it ... let the user save the "video" as file and then you will see, it works for "video" too

Comment: There's no relation between your code and youtube

Comment: when i try to upload mp4 file,browser shows me snap error

Comment: i want to store youtube video..how would i do it

Comment: how about trying this-> download a video of less than 2 MB, and check if it is uploaded?

Comment: @rakesh shewale it worked for 2mb file thanks,bt if user want to upload online video,what changes should i do in code

Comment: I suggest you to ask another question for the that. For your current question, I will post an answer

Answer (score 0):

By default, maximum upload_limit is set to 2 MB. So if you try to upload any file with size more than 2 MB, it will fail.

To change it, please edit your `php.ini` and set

```
upload_max_filesize = 40M ; you may set it according to your need
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PHP has several configuration options to limit resources consumed by scripts. By default, PHP is set to allow uploads of files with a size of 2MB or less.

Try increasing the following values in php.ini, for example:

memory_limit = 32M
upload_max_filesize = 24M
post_max_size = 32M

If the upload_max_filesize is larger than post_max_size, you must increase post_max_size so that it is bigger than upload_max_size.

If the value of post_max_size is larger than memory_limit, you must increase memory_limit so that it is larger than post_max_size.

There are multiple ways to edit php.ini
```

I hope this helps you